# Contact list in Gmail to quickly compose emails to no longer appears

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I used to have names of most used contacts to the left of all my emails.  Now it's
gone.  All I had to do is click on a name and I could then compose an email to them.
How do I get that list back?

Answer (score 1):

On the bottom left there is a chat symbol (like an SMS message). Click that and they should reappear. That's the toggle button.